# CSS - Background image is being truncated

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set a non scrolling background image(1170x700) to an element() which is 1170px wide. For that I used following css

```
.container
{
    background:url("bg-image1170x700.gif") no-repeat fixed center top #fff;
}
```

PROBLEM :- Initially the image is being truncated and if I scroll down its displays correctly. Not sure what am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by truncated? Can you attach an image of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size):

```
.container
{
    background:url("bg-image1170x700.gif") no-repeat fixed center top #fff;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Whenever downvoting it is always better to tell the reason. Please share the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying it fixed. It is most likely being hidden by another element, and when you scroll it scrolls out from behind that element

Comment: Yes you are right. I removed other elements and it shows correct then. Actually I am using twitter bootstrap and that container is bootstrap class. Not sure why its being hidden by another element. Since it has only some containers in its top and an navbar.

Comment: Sorry I am working on my local. I added a border around container and it seems container is not being hidden by any element. But background is going above the container.Its really strange!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of it? Do you have anything absolutely positioned?

Comment: No nothing is absolute positioned. Some elements are floating but I have cleared float as well.But no luck.